# Browser Window Gone in Latest Xcode?

Tags: core-data, xcode4

Has the browser window been removed from the latest version of Xcode? I've seen this window in an iOS class I watched online and again in a book I have. I can't find anything in the View menu to turn it on.

I'm running Lion and the latest version of Xcode. I created a new project with Core Data turned on and then built it. I then clicked on .xcdatamodeld file and I get a graphic window with the default table in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate to be answering my own question again. I like to keep my answer rate at 100%. Since I didn't get a response here, I tried the Apple developer forums. It turn out the Xcode 4.* changed the interface and this series of windows no longer exist. The same functions can be found in other locations.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the project browser on the left? You enable that using the 'view' buttons on the right side of the toolbar.
The toolbar might be hidden though, so go to the view menu and select "Show toolbar" if needed.

Then select the fourth button from the right on the toolbar, it is the first button in the set of view buttons. This shows the Navigator View on the left of your screen, which has 7 selectors on the top. The leftmost will give you the project browser (project navigator), the one next to it is the symbol navigator.

Comment: No, I know how to turn that one on and off. This is a three pane window that is at the top of the window with the class graphs. One pain lists the classes, another the properties, and the third the attributes.